# Candy Crush on HTC Desire?

Tags: google-play-store, htc-desire, candy-crush-saga

Am I not able to install Candy Crush game on my HTC Desire.

The telephone is not rooted and just hard reset
How can I solve it?

Comment: Why are you not able to install it? What happens when you try?

Comment: Error: device not competible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device does not support all of the features, candy crush requires, and therefor the play store will not allow you to install it.

You can attempt to download the APK from the interweb or try an alternative repository. Amazon app store perhaps?